# Why does UIViewRepresentable take all of the available space?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider this simple reproducible example that uses UIViewRepresentable:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyTextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        return UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = String(repeating: "Hello World!", count: 5)
        uiView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 60)
        uiView.textColor = .white
        uiView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyTextView()
    }
}

struct Content_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I would expect that `MyTextView()`'s size is determined by the size of the text view,
but it just occupies as much space as it can, as shown in the image below:

[image: Example UITextView]

#### Question

How can I make a `UIViewRepresentable` view that only takes the required space it needs?
Or e.g. the required space that the children need?

#### Note

This not only happens with `UITextView`, and I know that for `UILabel` setting
`.fixedSize()` solves the problem, but I'm looking for a solution for any type of `UIView`.

Comment: Why would you use an UIViewRepresentable on this case as SwiftUI does the job better?

Comment: I'm not using this particular view in my app, this is just an example to focus on the problem at hand

Comment: Here would be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868307/how-to-set-the-size-of-an-uiviewrepresentable. The trick is to add the modifier `.fixedSize()` to the representable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the size of an UIViewRepresentable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868307/how-to-set-the-size-of-an-uiviewrepresentable)